# grep specific number after string

Tags: bash, shell, grep

So I'm currently trying to make a script for gptfdisk and I need to get the "Partition unique GUID". This is the output I get:

```
Partition GUID code: 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (Apple HFS/HFS+)
Partition unique GUID: 677EDC3D-8AB1-458F-B849-F8B609339391
First sector: 352676 (at 1.3 GiB)
Last sector: 3899397 (at 14.9 GiB)
Partition size: 3546722 sectors (13.5 GiB)
Attribute flags: 0003000000000000
Partition name: 'Data'
```

In the end I want to have just the

```
677EDC3D-8AB1-458F-B849-F8B609339391
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I've already seen that post, though the answer does not quite accomplish what I need.

Comment: How does `grep -oP '(?<=^Partition unique GUID: ).*' infile` not work?

Comment: Perl is not supported in my version of grep

Comment: Then how does the first suggestion in the accepted answer, `grep 'Partition unique GUID:' infile | sed 's/^.*: //'`, not work?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I get the number, though I also get an unwanted part before it. It looks like this: https://ghostbin.com/paste/eovoq

Comment: That's probably output to standard error and has nothing to do with grep. Try suppressing it by replacing `gptfdisk /dev/rdisk0s1` by `gptfdisk /dev/rdisk0s1 2> /dev/null`, i.e., redirecting error output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Or alternatively, pipe both stderr and stdout to grep by using `gptfdisk /dev/rdisk0s1 |&`.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  That worked for me, thank you.

Comment: Now if you want to be super awesome, you can accept the duplicate as such.

Answer (score 1):

This will do :

```
sed -n '/unique GUID/{s/.* GUID: //p}' your_file
```

or if you wish to pipe some output do :

```
command | sed -n '/unique GUID/{s/.* GUID: //p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

grep wih Perl regex:

```
grep -oP '(?<=unique GUID: ).*' file
677EDC3D-8AB1-458F-B849-F8B609339391
```

Or using two `grep` operation:

```
grep 'unique GUID:' file | grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*$'
677EDC3D-8AB1-458F-B849-F8B609339391
```

Answer (score 0):

grep with awk -

`cat file | grep 'Partition unique GUID' | awk -F: '{print $2}'`